# Sunspot 2.1.0 RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, mongoid, sunspot

Running Rails 4.0.1, and Sunspot 2.1.0, I manage to run sunspot in development, but when I try to do query or index, I get the following error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     Not Found

Request Data: "fq=type%3AMatch&q=arsenal&defType=edismax&start=0&rows=10"

Backtrace: /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in `adapt_response'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/sunspot-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:45:in `execute'
/Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/sunspot-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:59:in `search'):
  app/models/match.rb:483:in `upcoming_games'
  app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:34:in `search'


  Rendered /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.1ms)
```

This is my sunspot.yml

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: ENV['WEBSOLR_URL']
    port: 80
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development
    # solr_home: solr
test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

**NOTE** I tried different solr_home configuration, tried removing solr folder and restarting sunspot as suggested elsewhere, and also made sure the pid Rails is trying to connect to is the same.

I know there are other similar posts, but none provided a solution that worked for me. Any idea?

For what it's worth, I'm using Mongoid. But that hardly seems related.

Comment: Can you access it from a browser, e.g. `http://localhost:8982/solr/development/select?q=*:*`?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the "path" directive from the production config in sunspot.yml, most probably solr_home is pointing to the default directory (/solr), in which index actually exist

can you try this:

$ ps aux | grep solr

and post the output here?